# azure Kustos query: avg response time for Urls

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I have urls(more than 10k) none are identical but similar and their response times.
For example:

```
URL                                                   Response time(ms)
https://abc@example.com/order/pick/123543               291
https://abc@example.com/deliver/open/1235               589
https://abc@example.com/reach/destination/12351223      390
https://abc@example.com/pack/box/square/12355444        771
https://abc@example.com/pack/box/square/343433          750
https://abc@example.com/order/1235321                   774
https://abc@example.com/order/size/                     433
```

I want to summarise and render it as time graph.
Please help me to count by specific name from URL eg: average response time for all the urls contains 'box' or 'order/size'

Please help me form a query.

Comment: This is the what I have got. Need some help to narrow the search down
                -----------------------------------------------------------------
custom logs
| where (itemType == 'test' and resultCode == 200 )
| summarize avg(duration) by name, bin(timestamp, 1h) 
| render timechart

Comment: to get only the urls you are interested in you can do a where clause like `| where name contains "order/size"` for example.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons for the response. But in time graph I want the result to be displayed as: order/size - 345, box - 454, pick - 456.   But I am getting full URLs instead.

Comment: Can you post the desired output given the input in your question? If you want to strip the domain name you can do `custom logs | where (itemType == 'test' and resultCode == 200 ) | summarize avg(duration) by name = replace("https://abc@example.com/", "", name), bin(timestamp, 1h) | render timechart`

Comment: Nitin, does the answer I posted answer your question? If yes, please accept it. If not, can you please update the question to be more specific on what you need?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
datatable(URL:string,ResponseTimeInMs:long) [
    "https://abc@example.com/order/pick/123543",291,
    "https://abc@example.com/deliver/open/1235",589,
    "https://abc@example.com/reach/destination/12351223",390,
    "https://abc@example.com/pack/box/square/12355444",771,
    "https://abc@example.com/pack/box/square/343433",750,
    "https://abc@example.com/order/1235321",774,
    "https://abc@example.com/order/size/",433
]
| extend PartialUrl = tostring(split(URL, "/")[3])
| summarize avg(ResponseTimeInMs) by PartialUrl
| order by avg_ResponseTimeInMs desc
```

Output:

```
|------------|----------------------|
| PartialUrl | avg_ResponseTimeInMs |
|------------|----------------------|
| pack       | 760.5                |
| deliver    | 589                  |
| order      | 499.333333333333     |
| reach      | 390                  |
|------------|----------------------|
```

Or, if you want `order` and `order/size` separately, then instead of `extend PartialUrl = tostring(split(URL, "/")[3])` write `extend PartialUrl = replace("[0-9]*", "", replace("https://abc@example.com/", "", URL))`, and you'll get the following output:

```
|--------------------|----------------------|
| PartialUrl         | avg_ResponseTimeInMs |
|--------------------|----------------------|
| order/             | 774                  |
| pack/box/square/   | 760.5                |
| deliver/open/      | 589                  |
| order/size/        | 433                  |
| reach/destination/ | 390                  |
| order/pick/        | 291                  |
|--------------------|----------------------|
```